Tomcat v9.0 server is failing to start on eclipse EE
Tomcat 9.0 server is failing to start if I create a servlet and servlet mapping in web.xml file, If I removed the servlet and servlet mapping on web.xml file server is running ?
Why that happens ?
I have tried to run my web application with servlet using tomcat v9.0 server, If I add my servlet and mapping on web.xml file, server is failing to start. if I removed my servlet and mapping on web.xml and mapping through annonation @WebServlet(/xxx) server is starting but while submiting the client request on the web page it is showing error page - given below.
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "String.trim()" because "in" is null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.trim()" because "in" is null
    java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
    controller.SaveServlet.doPost(SaveServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.86


Looks like SaveServlet is calling Double.parseDouble with a null argument (Maybe a nonexistent request parameter?).

You got NullPointerException in the method doPost while doing Double.parseDouble(null). Why the parameter is null? Because it isn't posted with the request and requrst.getParameter returns null. You should check parameters for null in the request that they exist before you assign them to the variable.
